# Superuser off-topic restrictions

Tags: discussion

My question here has to do with the off-topic restrictions in Superuser.  It seems that any question related to web applications is closed immediately as "off-topic."  I didn't realize these were off-limits until I was directed to read the FAQ.

What is the main purpose for restricting web-application questions from superuser?  I assume you could ask a question about Microsoft Word on Superuser, because it doesn't specifically disallow questions about desktop software, but what's the difference?  Can I ask a question about Excel, but not Google Docs Spreadsheets?  I guess the ultimate question is:  what specific community is superuser targeting with these restrictions?

I asked a question about Last.fm plugins for WordPress, and it was closed immediately.  If I was asking about how to *write* a last.fm plugin for Wordpress, would that be allowed?  (In that case, I'd probably ask on Stackoverflow... but anyway)  Or are any questions related to Wordpress strictly off-limits?

My other qualm with these moderation trends is that you often get redirected to some external Q&A site or forum, or are told that there might be a stack exchange site coming for that topic.  Personally, I'm not really interested in joining 10 different segmented communities, just to ask one computer-software related question.  Moreover, the more specific and segmented the stack exchange site is, the fewer users it will have, and the usefulness goes down exponentially.

Anyway, I vote to redo the FAQ for superuser to allow a broader range of computer/software questions!

Comment: [Superuser website applications policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy) discusses this in some depth.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't see that question in my search.  Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy is a broken link. (Not redirected either.)

Answer (score 6):

Let's say Super User was a site about automobiles.

**Just because you like to listen to the radio in your car, does not mean the automobile site is about radio stations.**

Radio *hardware* (aka the Web Browser) is on topic, but not the radio stations (Web Sites) you tune in with them. There needs to be a separate site for radio listening enthusiasts -- there's absolutely nothing wrong with people who love to listen to the radio, and view radio listening as the primary function of their automobile -- but that's a *fundamentally different community* than car nuts.

(In other words, unless your computer effectively stops functioning when disconnected from the internet -- it's not a core function. I realize this day is coming, but until we're there, I support SU as the "car nuts" computer site, not the "I loves tuning me in some radio stations" computer site.)

That said, I fully support [a proposal for a site about web applications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications), I think we need one -- but broadening the already-too-broad-scope of Super User is not a forumula for success.

Comment: This seems really arbitrary, considering that questions about many (most?) web-apps have strapped-in versions as well, which in some cases (e.g. Open Office <-> Google Docs) work very similarly. Or else, why are desktop applications on topic at all? (At the very least, we need a better analogy! ;-)